# Free Access to DB2 via ODBC

Tags: .net, odbc, db2

Is there a free option to connect to DB2 via ODBC on within my .NET app?  I believe the most common ways require a license:

1. Data Direct $$$$
2. IBM Client Access
3. Host Integration Server

I just want to install an ODBC driver that I could access from a C# app.

Comment: You need data direct or db2 connect only to connect to DB2 on host systems (Mainframe or As/400).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need an ODBC driver, don't you? I suppose any DB2 database connection possibility from .NET should fit your needs.

This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DotnetDb2.aspx) gives a good overview of the options for connecting to a DB2 database from the .NET framework.